# How does Sara become a child in Mermaid Melody?

Tags: mermaid-melody

I watched this anime when I was in grade 4. 
I still can't see why Sara (the orange mermaid) becomes a child.

[image: Sara]

[image: other mermaids]

Answer (score 2):

Sara had lost her memories but the few fragments of her former self who loved Masahiro created a body. So the child form of Sara is the feeling she had for Masahiro.